# Setting up a miner with Eligius

Tags: mining-pools, eligius

In the last few hours I am getting 100% connection rejections from Eligius. I am using a Mac and the Asteroid miner GUI. I also have MacMiner setup. both are not failing after about a month of successfully working.  But that is not the point of the question.

My question is trying to understand the pool URL, here is what Eligius provides:
Stratum Host: stratum.mining.eligius.st Port: 3334 | Getwork Host: getwork.mining.eligius.st Port: 8337 GBT Host: gbt.mining.eligius.st Port: 9337

I have been using "http://gbt.mining.eligius.st:9337"

Question 1: Why is the scheme missing, that is "http://", etc. It needs to be entered as part of the pool URL, what if any scheme should be entered?

Also is there some reason the scheme is not provided? Or it just a lazy web developer?

Question 2:
Please direct me to some information about the host types: Stratum, Getwork and GBT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the last few hours I am getting 100% connection rejections from
>   Eligius. I am using a Mac and the Asteroid miner GUI. I also have
>   MacMiner setup. both are not failing after about a month of
>   successfully working. But that is not the point of the question.

Check your ISP, check luke's threads on btctalk and on eligius or their IRC chan #Eligius on freenode. They can give you the best help with support. A stackexchange unfortunately is not a support page for a website.

> My question is trying to understand the pool URL, here is what Eligius
>   provides: Stratum Host: stratum.mining.eligius.st Port: 3334 | Getwork
>   Host: getwork.mining.eligius.st Port: 8337 GBT Host:
>   gbt.mining.eligius.st Port: 9337
>
> I have been using "http://gbt.mining.eligius.st:9337"

Thanks for some detailed info.

> Question 1: Why is the scheme missing, that is "http://", etc. It
>   needs to be entered as part of the pool URL, what if any scheme should
>   be entered?

stratum+tcp://stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334

I believe i explained the rest of the question below.

> Also is there some reason the scheme is not provided? Or it just a
>   lazy web developer?

It's assumed that in bitcoin mining you have an idea of what a stratum's protocol is and the requirements/settings for it. Plus some newer miner programs auto detect stratum/gbt then fall back to getwork if there is not a template available. I wouldn't call it a lazy web developer. Just one who is more technical and not the best with making n00b friendly how to's.

> Question 2: Please direct me to some information about the host types:
>   Stratum, Getwork and GBT.
>   Let me give a light explanation of each along with some links

Getwork was the original bitcoin mining protocol. It is still around, but not used very much except by some pools for legacy support (mostly asicminer blades/cubes). Getwork uses the standard rpc connect commands to get new work. Since a third party miner does not have the block chain, it has to ask for a new piece of work to hash.
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork

Stratum mining is an overlay protocol that allows thin clients as well as a method of sending templates via the stratum protocol.
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Stratum

GBT (getblocktemplate)
This is simply allowing you to get the entire template of a block. A template is the entire list of transactions needed to hash out the block. This is usually updated every minute. This allows ASIC miners not to have issues with as many rejected shares and stale shares (like they would with GetWork)
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate

Source: Me. (I'm an alt-chain pool op and a longtime bitcoiner)

As always
Any errors/questions/comments feel free to let me know in a positive manner.

Comment: Great into on the protocols.  Sorry, I have t go with lazy. Giving full information is part of a good user interface. If the information is not there there is no way to get past noob-hood. That some clients will automatically fill-in the correct scheme is a partial answer **if** they supply that information, both in the positive and negative. But they seem to fall back on the pool supplying that information. I spent substantial time looking for the definitive answer before I asked here, thanks for you answer. As for bitcointalk I wish I could get an account setup there.